# More than three columns in css

Tags: css, layout

What is the best method for creating 3-8 columns in a css page.  Ideally they will just stack from left to right.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

use div and css with float attribute

Answer (score 0):

- Multiple divs with display: inline-block (decent, but lacks support in old browsers)
- Multiple divs with float: left or right (floats are tough to work with and can make your layout inflexible in other ways)
- Multiple divs with display: table-cell (some neat effects like auto width in my tests, but I'm wary of the level of cross-browser support here)

And then there's [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603222/columns-with-css-without-using-multiple-divs).

Answer (score 0):

For mozilla and webkit use the `[-moz-|-webkit-]column-count` property. You use it like this

```
<div id="mcol">
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
</div>

#mcol {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

See this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) for more details and other useful properties for multiple columns.

For IE, see the methods in this [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/) or use a script.

Comment: I like this method.  When i add a border to that, it only add's it around all three columns instead of seperating the three.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Use the `[-moz-|-webkit-]column-rule` property in the [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html#link3) I mentioned.